# Google API returning error accessNotConfigured

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I recieve This a google error when using the url directly along with a newly created project (with no other projects listed) I continously get the below error....

```
{
             "error": {
              "errors": [
               {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
                "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
               }
              ],
              "code": 403,
              "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
             }
            }
```

I know there have seen a few posts on this subject. and I have followed the instructions listed. I even created new project...

1. turned on fusion table in console (tried with both only fusion api on and nothering else & standard api
2. generated public key with the referers *
3. Consent screen filled out
4. fusion table Download allowed checked
5. shared with permission for "anyone with link" is selected

url = https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/105Otxh5ltQsKBr-ABqYJ8vBuB6E9Ped2MfXj3AZy/templates?&key=AIzaSyCr_wIc0aEHUG6Pl08kHDYLqWRB_PqZsE0

docid = 105Otxh5ltQsKBr-ABqYJ8vBuB6E9Ped2MfXj3AZy

key = AIzaSyCr_wIc0aEHUG6Pl08kHDYLqWRB_PqZsE0

Just what am I missing. I have the google php api client to use a service account.. but if I cant pull up the tables, query or anything via the base api url then i can move forward... untill then Im stuck. Thank in advance anyone!